# sed inline replacement and without having to create a file

Tags: sed

I'm trying to do a replacement inline in a configuration file after defore deploying this file.
I looked in the sed documentation but I can't get it working. Even with -e
For now I mv into .back file and then sed to the file, finishing by rm the file.
I'm sure there's an easier way to do that but can't get it working.

Thanks

mv file.conf file.back
sed s/string/anotherstring/ file.back > file.conf
rm file.back

Comment: "but I can't get it working" you're going to need to describe which bit fails, and why.

Comment: +1 @EightBitTony, and you should also take the time to reformat your question to be more readable.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to modify files content instantly you can use the `sed -e 's/your/expression/g' -i filename`.  You can add a `-i.bak` to backup the original file before any change happens.

Adding, that `sed` is a **Stream EDitor** and you rather should use  `ed` or `ex`.

Update example:

```
[val0x00ff@localhost dir1]$ ls
file
[val0x00ff@localhost dir1]$ cat file 
test
anothertest
hangethisLine/g

[val0x00ff@localhost dir1]$ sed -i.bak 's/test/substitute_to_this/g' file 
[val0x00ff@localhost dir1]$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 val0x00ff val0x00ff 62 Aug 28 14:59 file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 val0x00ff val0x00ff 34 Aug 28 14:58 file.bak
[val0x00ff@localhost dir1]$ cat file
substitute_to_this
anothersubstitute_to_this
hangethisLine/g

[val0x00ff@localhost dir1]$ cat file.bak 
test
anothertest
hangethisLine/g
```

See how `-i.bak` creates a backup file automatically to protect us from overriding the file by accident.

See lin http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed  for examples using the `ed` editor.

Comment: what's the difference with `sed 's/your/expression/g' -i filename` ?

Comment: There is very little difference with one sed expression (man page says -e "add the script to the commands to be executed") but if you want to use more than one you need -e for each sed command in the command line.

Comment: @Kwaio There is no difference. `-i.back` can be placed either in the beginning of the `sed` expression as well as just before the `filename`.

Comment: I'm also intrested in the effect of the omission of the 's' in front of the replacement pattern.

Comment: @Kwaio `s` in `s/.../..../`  stands for `substitute`. If you need to delete a pattern you clearly don't want to substitute it but just delete it. When this is the case you'd `sed '/pattern_to_delete/d' filename`. We don't need `s` now. Hope I understood your question and hope it clarifies it.

Comment: So there is really a 's' missing at the first line of this answer. I didn't want to state it until you confirm but I guessed well.

Comment: Yes. However in the examlple down there I've included `s'. Thanks for pointing that out